# Can't find documentation on a cool Angular feature for two-way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, code-documentation, two-way-binding

This is **not** a question on how to do Angular bindings. It's not about `ngModel` etc.

It's about a feature that I've just been educated on, seemingly working and quite nicely.

I've never heard of it and I can't confirm it in any documentation I've looked into.

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547337/unsure-how-to-apply-two-way-binding-on-angular-for-a-custom-component) and got a few answers, [one of which](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547437/8744999) was spot-on and easy to implement.

Basically, it's about the two-way binding that works automagically without implementing `ControlValueAccessor` nor manually mapping values to the model in the view component from the custom control component. I only had to put in an `@Output` suffixed by *Change* in the custom component and banana-box in the view component and tada! it works.

*custom.component.ts*

```
@Input() value: string;
@Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<string>;
```

*view.component.html*

```
<app-custom [(value)]="model.someField"></app-custom>
<app-custom [(value)]="model.anotherField"></app-custom>
```

Where is this behavior documented? Is it some special case of `ngModel` that I don't comprehend or just a nice feature not widely known?

I'm afraid that it's just a fluke and not something that's going to be supported in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is proper and documented in [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-). it is not some "un official hack"

According to docs:

> Angular offers a special two-way data binding syntax for this purpose,
>   [()]. The [()] syntax combines the brackets of property binding, [],
>   with the parentheses of event binding, ().
>   The [()] syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a settable
>   property called x and a corresponding event named xChange. Here's a
>   SizerComponent that fits this pattern. It has a size value property
>   and a companion sizeChange event:

The official docs even gives an example of it

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sizer',
  templateUrl: './sizer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sizer.component.css']
})
export class SizerComponent {


  @Input()  size: number | string;
  @Output() sizeChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  dec() { this.resize(-1); }
  inc() { this.resize(+1); }

  resize(delta: number) {
    this.size = Math.min(40, Math.max(8, +this.size + delta));
    this.sizeChange.emit(this.size);
  }

}
```

so rest assured it is not something which might be removed without any notice.

## BUT

just an [FYI](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel) if you plan on using `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

Comment: Regarding your butt - it says that *has been deprecated for a few reasons* about `ngModel`. Am I to understand that the concept isn't used in Angular 7 at all? That's a first time I hear about this. I prefer the *x* and *xChange* pattern immensely better.

Comment: you can use x and xChange pattern for custom components in all angular version . Starting with version 7 you can not ngModel and ngModelChange  i.e template driven form. the reasons are given in the link above

Answer (score 2):

Two-way bindings (or bananabox) are quite common and a nifty little thing for those dumb/smart component patterns.

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-

Don't worry, it's not going away

Comment: Please read the full content of the question. It's not nearly as broad as the banana notations for two way binding. It's very specific related to the suffix *xxxChange* which I wasn't even aware of.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana okay, then i'm not really sure of what you are asking about, if it's not documumentation on [()]. [()] is essentially the same as <component [value]="valueSource" (valueChange)="valueSouce"></component>. Only with the "Change" suffix, can angular know they are the same value. And the event change value, should be the property binding's source value.

You can even bind the event binding to a method and do something with the event there.

Comment: Not sure how to elaborate it further. The question isn't "*what's a banana box and how does it work*". It's "*where is the effect suffix **Change** documented*".